# UDF input a table and output a table

Tags: t-sql

Am trying to work out how to create a user defined function that will accept one input parameter as a table, then output a table which can then be worked with in the function that calls it, as a table. From the examples I have been working with I can either input a table or get a table back out but not both
Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: It would be helpful to tell a bit more of what you are trying to do. For example you can pass a table like structure by using XML. If you want to pass a real table you can do it by passing the table name and working with it in dynamic sql. Also you can use a global temp table to work with your function but it depends a lot on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ideally I would like to define an input to the UDF as a table  and then get it's results as a table. ie                  CREATE FUNCTION ExampleFunction(@TABLE AS TABLE(
       SomePrimaryKey [int] NULL
     ) READONLY,)
RETURNS @SomethingElse TABLE
   (
    SomePrimaryKey int,
    SomeData nvarchar(80),
    SomeMoreData      int
   )

Comment: Another Stored procedure could then call on this giving it a table of data and then getting back a table of data to continue processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help I think I've got it.

```
--DROP TYPE TableType
CREATE TYPE TableType 
AS TABLE (SomePrimaryKey_ID INT)
GO 


--DROP FUNCTION Example
CREATE FUNCTION Example( @TableName TableType READONLY)
RETURNS @Test TABLE
(
intcfmno INT
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @testing AS VARCHAR --<< just checking that I can still declare a variable in the funciton
INSERT @Test
SELECT 22
RETURN 
END


-- testing the function
DECLARE @myTable TableType
INSERT INTO @myTable(SomePrimaryKey_ID) VALUES(111)
--SELECT * FROM @myTable
SELECT * from Example(@myTable)
```

Comment: and I might of jumped the gun. This will work without a problem if I'm on the master db but as soon as I go to a user db then it fails with a scalar error message. Checked the permissions on the type, and function. Am running as sa as well. Have worked around the problem with a date input and a table output. But would really like to of done it properly.

Comment: And for anyone out there. The issue was caused b/c of the compatibility level of the db. Can use     DECLARE @sql varchar(250)
set @sql='alter database '+quotename(db_name())+' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90';
exec(@sql)